# Find queries appear automatically in the find fields for other applications

Tags: high-sierra, settings, search

After years on a much older version of Mac OS, I'm now on v. 10.13.2, and I observe strange behavior when I use `find` functionality, in various applications.

If I search for some string in one application, when I open the search interface in another application, the same string auto-populates the search field.

It happens even when the search string is not in the clipboard, so it isn't just that the clipboard is autopasting — there's an actual transfer of the search string across applications. Affected applications include current versions of BBEdit, NisusWriter, Chrome, Firefox, the built-in Dictionary, Terminal — so I assume it's happening at the level of the operating system.

This is intrusive and unwelcome default behavior, and I'd like to know how to turn it off. I see some unanswered questions about the same issue here and there (for instance, ["Disable search field syncing"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306080/disable-search-field-syncing), ["Why does a find field value in one application show up in a the find field of another application?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80894/why-does-a-find-field-value-in-one-application-show-up-in-a-the-find-field-of-an)).